# Why is this SPIM/MIPS program for summing the even integers in an array not working?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, spim, qtspim

I'm new to MIPS, so if you see anything that doesn't make sense, then that's why.

I'm trying to sum only the even values of the array in my code, and then stick the result in $10. I've included what I've written so far. When the program is executed it hangs and gives me a few errors: "Exception occurred at PC=0x0040001c" and "Bad address in data/stack read 0x10040000" and "Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x80000180."

```
.text

.globl main


main:

lui $16,0x1000
lw  $17,0($16)
addiu $16, $16, 4
addiu $18, $0, 2
addiu $19, $0, 32

loop:

beq $16, $19, exit
sll $0, $0, 0
lw  $17,0($16)
sll $0, $0, 0
div $17, $18
mfhi $13
beq $13, $0, even
sll $0, $0, 0
addiu $16, $16, 4
j loop
sll $0, $0, 0

even:

add $10, $10, $17
addiu $16, $16, 4

j loop
sll $0, $0, 0

exit:

sll $0, $0, 0

.data
size: .word 8
array: .word 23, -12, 45, -32, 52, -72, 8, 13
```

I get -56 in $10, but the result should be 25 in $10.

Comment: Use you simulator to single step the program and see where it goes wrong. Also, if you see your question comes out with broken formatting, use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55761097/edit) and the code formatting toolbar button to fix it. One obvious problem is at `exit` you only have a `sll` for whatever reason, but your program is otherwise not exiting.

Answer (score 1):

First issue:

I'm assuming that `lui $16,0x1000`, is meant to be getting the start of users memory for getting the size, array etc, and `lw  $17,0($16)` get size into $17

Using that

$16 = 0x10000000
$17 = 0

And obviously all the other reads from the array in $16 will be wrong.

If I use `la $16, size`, I get:

$16 = 0x10010000
$17 = 8

And the other reads for the array should be better.

Next Issue:

`beq $16, $19, exit` is 'goto exit if $16 (current address in array you are at) == $19 which you had set to 32, so its not going to exit any time soon, and be attempting access memory it shouldn't be

Other notes:
`sll $0, $0, 0` does nothing much $0 = 0<<0 - not sure what you are thinking its doing

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code.
1. you do not read array or size to get parameters of your data
2. your loop control is incorrect. You use $16 (supposed to be @array and initialized at 1k), add 4 and test when it reaches 32... I would really advise you do have separate separate registers to count loop iterations and to compute arrays addresses
4. You should call exit() (syscall 10) at the end, otherwise your simulator will try to execute your data and will issue  "Attempt to execute non-instruction at ...".
5. organization of your program with many branches is complex and error prone.  Putting loops tests at the end and inverting tests generally leads to clearer code.
6. Why do you insert all these nops (`sll $0, $0, 0`)? Most are not required, and I would not advise you to use delayed loads to learn mips. Once you master it, it is another story.
7. Testing if a number is odd or even do not require a division. Just test the value of its LSB.

Here is a working code:

```
.text
.globl main
main:
        la $16,array   # $16==@array
        la $19,size    # $19 =@size
        lw $19,0($19)  # $19=size of array(in words)
        addi $20, $0,0 # i=0
loop:
        lw  $17,0($16)    # $17=*array
        andi $13,$17,1    # get lsb to know is $17 is odd or even
        bne $13, $0, odd  # skip accumulation if $17 is odd
        add $10, $10, $17 # accumulate sum of evens
odd:    
        addiu $16, $16, 4 # array++
        addiu $20,$20,1   # i++
        bne $20, $19, loop# goto loop if i!= size

exit:
        addi $2,$0,10    # write 10 in $v0 ($2) to call
        syscall          # syscall 10 (exit)

.data
size:  .word 8
array: .word 23, -12, 45, -32, 52, -72, 8, 13
```